# Unable to change background color after displaying csv values into canvas frame

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I create canvas Frame with `create_window`.
I have a "emp.csv" file with three columns [CountryCode, CountryName, Population].
After the CSV data is read and placed into the frame and I am unable to  change the background color to "white".
It still remains gray. For that what needs to be modify?

***emp.csv***

```
     CountryCode,CountryName,Population
        500,country1,100000
        501,country2,100000
        502,country3,100000
```

***code***

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk 
import tkinter as tk 
import tkinter.ttk
import csv
from tkinter import filedialog

class Employee():   
    def __init__(self):   
        create_widgets(self)

def myfunction(event):
    canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"),width=450,height=300) 

root=Tk()
sizex = 800
sizey = 600
posx  = 100
posy  = 100
root.title("My Appication")
root.wm_geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (sizex, sizey, posx, posy))
myframe=Frame(root,relief=GROOVE,width=450,height=400,bd=2,background="white")
myframe.place(x=50,y=100)
canvas=Canvas(myframe)
scrollable_frame=Frame(canvas)
myscrollbar=Scrollbar(myframe,orient="vertical",command=canvas.yview)
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=myscrollbar.set,bg='white')
myscrollbar.pack(side="right",fill="y")
canvas.pack(side="left")
canvas.create_window((0,0),window=scrollable_frame,anchor='nw' )
scrollable_frame.bind("<Configure>",myfunction)

def create_widgets(self):
    self.Button_readcsv= Button(root,text ="Browse CSV ", command = read_csvfile)
    self.Button_readcsv.place(x=40, y=40)       
 
def read_csvfile():          
    filepath=filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Open file",filetypes=(("CSV Files","*.csv"),)) 
    try:
            with open(filepath) as f:
                    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=',')
                    headers = reader.fieldnames
                    i=0
                    tk.Label(scrollable_frame, text=headers[0] ).grid(row=i,column=1)               
                    tk.Label(scrollable_frame, text=headers[1]).grid(row=i,column=2)
                    tk.Label(scrollable_frame, text=headers[2]).grid(row=i,column=3)
                    for row in reader:
                        i=i+1
                        CountryCode = row[headers[0]]
                        CountryName = row[headers[1]]    
                        Population= row[headers[2]]                                    
                        tk.Label(scrollable_frame,text=CountryCode).grid(row=i,column=1)
                        tk.Label(scrollable_frame, text=CountryName).grid(row=i,column=2)      
                        tk.Label(scrollable_frame, text=Population).grid(row=i,column=3)  
    except(IOError):
                print(" Error Reading in CSV File ")       
       
def main():     
   empobj = Employee()
   root.mainloop()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You did not specify the `bg` option when creating `scrollable_frame`: `scrollable_frame=Frame(canvas)`.  So it is gray by default.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is working now